# Is it possible to use Model manager to filter directly from template?

Tags: django

I have  created  a model manager to be able to filter data

```
class BOMVersion_default_active_Manager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BOMVersion_default_active, self).get_queryset().filter(is_default=True,is_active=True)


@with_author 
class BOMVersion(models.Model): 
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    material =  models.ForeignKey(Material)
    default_active_objects = BOMVersion_default_active_Manager()
```

I try to use it in my nested for loop from  template ( since I cant filter directly in template and this is how i decided to overcome this limitation)

```
{% for bomversion in soproduct.product.material.bomversion.default_active_objects_set.all %}
```

But I am not getting any output. What could be the problem? Can I do it in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom `Manager` is not the right way to go. You need to carefully read the whole  [Django Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#managers) article.

In this situation what you need is a custom `QuerySet`. Something like this:

```
class BOMVersionQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_active=True)

    def default(self):
        return self.filter(is_default=True)

@with_author 
class BOMVersion(models.Model): 
    version = IntegerVersionField( )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    material =  models.ForeignKey(Material)

    objects = BOMVersionQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Now you can use `.active()` and `.default()` methods to filter any `BOMVersion-QuerySet`. This is actually what you got when you use the reverse relation from `Material` model, `material.bomversion_set` is a `BOMVersion-QuerySet` and thus you don't have access to `BOMVersion.objects`, but since its a  `BOMVersion-QuerySet` you can use `.active()` and `.default()`

```
{% for bomversion in soproduct.product.material.bomversion_set.default.active %}
```

However, again this is completely wrong and my advice is not to do it in the template. Use the view to build you querysets, and only iterate them in the template.

Why its bad in the template? Because right now you are making 1 query per `material` object, and there is no way to optimize it unless you use `prefetch_related`, but guess what? You can't use `prefetch_related` in the django template system. (Its on purpose, and the reason is to not do stuff like that in the template), so the correct approach is to make something similar to this:

```
#in the view:
soproduct = SoProduct.objects.select_related('product__material').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'product__material__bomversion_set',
        queryset=BOMVersion.objects.default().active()
        to_attr='default_active_bomversions'
    )
).get(pk=soproduct_id)

#in the template:
{% for bomversion in soproduct.product.material.default_active_bomversions %}
```

Now you are gonna make 1 query for the `soproduct` with its related `product` and `material` data and 1 more query for the requested `default_active_bomversions`.